# ubuntu 12.04 - intel hd4600 haswell graphics issue

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, software-installation, tearing

Ubuntu 12.04 is not 'recognizing' my intel haswell i5 hd4600 graphics (which 13.04 does). I have the traditional 2d desktop and am seeing copious amounts of screen-tearing. The main vice is that I cannot drag windows around the desktops in expo.

Is there a way to fetch the drivers that work in Ubuntu 13.04 to be on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop or some other workaround? I have already installed and updated from the 'x-swat' graphics repo.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the desired effect (OpenGL/3D supported desktop) by performing these steps:

In terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
```

I then rebooted and went to my updater settings and allowed precise-proposed updates before performing a dist-upgrade and rebooting again.
[image]

I can now drag windows around in expo, and I no longer suffer from screen tearing. Also, the ring-switcher from compiz now works.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310341/do-graphics-drivers-for-intel-hd-4600-exist/323973)

New install of Ubuntu Precise available today already includes Quantal kernel and x-server. I have installed Raring kernel and x-server to solve issues with startup and network using:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```

Reasons ad more comments are explained in linked article.

Comment: Yes it appears that if you install ubuntu 12.04 today then it is no longer an issue so this question is now redundant, but at the time when it was asked, it was not.